# How did Mahendra Baahubali gain such skills and power?

Tags: character, baahubali-the-beginning, baahubali-2-the-conclusion

It is known that Amarendra Baahubali underwent (formal) training and got power in terms of muscle power, strategies, warrior skills etc., Some scenes of *Baahubali: The Beginning* and *Baahubali: The Conclusion* show his rigorous training.

Coming to Mahendra Baahubali, he was brought up without any training. My question is how Mahendra Baahubali got such power (mainly in terms of muscle power). He lifts Shivalinga, which is not possible for ordinary people around him.

I am guessing two possible reasons for it:

1. He made the **habit of climbing the water hills** from his childhood and spending most of his time doing this activity caused his muscle power.
2. He is the son of Amarendra Baahubali and hence he got most of the power **genetically**.

Which of the reasons is significant? Are there any other reasons for it?

Comment: It's a Bollywood movie you know.

Comment: @VarunAgw Technically, it is not. It is a Telugu move dubbed into other languages.

Answer (score 2):

Both the reasons you gave seem valid but second reason looks more appropriate.

Mahendra Bahubali got his power (both physically and mentally) from his father Amarendra Bahubali. Here are some reasons why

- Mahendra Bahubali's personality is exactly same as his father Amarendra Bahubali which is due to genes. This strongly suggests that he is same as his father in many aspects. There is only difference in weight. Amarendra Bahubali's weight is more than Mahendra Bahubali.
- He is physically strong. He is not hurt very much even when he falls from great heights. See [Dheevara song](https://youtu.be/k55g2zx1ceI) from *Baahubali: The Beginning*. He is innovative when he thinks. It is known from the same song when he makes bow.
- More support is given to this opinion from *Baahubali : The Conclusion* 
  in the scene where Mahendra and his supporters enter the fort in Mahishmati. Kattappa says:

> You are son of Amarendra Bahubali who can fill light in the quite dark with his intelligence.

After this dialogue, he thinks and uses trees to enter the fort. This is same as Amarendra Bahubali helping masses of Mahishmati kingdom (Seen in [Dandalayya/Jay jaykara song).

Hence, we can conclude that he got his skills and powers mainly from his father. These skills were hone by his habit of climbing water falls and mountains since his childhood.